# SQL: Using row values as column headers

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I'm building a fairly large table for a client, and they want the data represented in a certain way. My table is currently like this:

```
DATE_RECEIVED | NAME  |      DOB    | ANALYTE | RESULT
  'YYYY/MM'   |STRING |'MM/DD/YYYY' | String  | String
   2011/03    |Name, A| 07/31/1056  |  AAAA   | Positive
   2011/03    |Name, A| 07/31/1056  |  BBBB   | Negative
```

What I need to do is something like a pivot - each "Analyte" is to be its own column, with the "result" being the value in the column, like this:

```
DATE_RECEIVED | NAME  |     DOB     |   AAAA   |   BBBB   |
   2011/03    |Name, A| 07/31/1056  | Positive | Negative |
```

I've tried a few things with PIVOT, but I think that I'm still too novice to understand how the logic for that function works. Either that, or the version of SQL I'm using doesn't support pivoting. Looking through similar questions on this site didn't really get me any closer to solving the problem because I don't really feel like I understand my problem well enough to know what I need to do to fix it. Anyway, I'm completely stumped. If anyone could give me a place to start, that would be extremely helpful. Thanks!

...Also, I know I'm using Oracle SQL, but I don't know what version. If it helps, I'm writing everything in TOAD for Oracle version 12.6.

Comment: Pivot requires 11g; you can check your version with `select version from product_component_version where product like 'Oracle Database%'`. (There are probably simpler ways to check...). Are the `analyte` values a finite set, or can they be set to anything?

Comment: There are many possible analyte values, and I don't know them all. The version is 11.2.0.3.0

Comment: Is there a unique constraint involved? i.e., For every date_received + name + DOB there will be only one record with analyte='AAA'? Because if not then you need to define how to handle multiple rows for the same Analyte and other key components.

Comment: Each Analyte will only have 1 result per name/date. Also, each name/date may have some or all analytes with results. For example, Name_A might have results for analyte AAA and BBB, and Name_B would have results for AAA and CCC, and Name_C would have AAA, BBB, and CCC results.

Comment: You can write two functions, one which replies the AAAA status, one which replies the BBB status, both with input of Primary Key of that table. If you then make a Select with a Group By, you can call those functions in virtual column "AAAA" and "BBBB"

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use `PIVOT` (maybe your version of Oracle doesn't support it), then it is possible to use `CASE` instead together with an aggregate:

```
SELECT date_received, name, dob
     , MAX(CASE WHEN analyte = 'AAAA' THEN result END) AS aaaa
     , MAX(CASE WHEN analyte = 'BBBB' THEN result END) AS bbbb
  FROM mytable
 GROUP BY date_received, name, dob
```

**UPDATE:** Here is how you might accomplish the same thing with `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT date_received, name, dob, analyte, result
    FROM mytable
) PIVOT ( MAX(result) FOR (analyte) IN ('AAAA' AS a,'BBBB' AS b) );
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/499ec/3)

Note that with a `PIVOT` you still need an aggregate function - `MAX()` will do here, and so will `MIN` if there is only one value! `AS` in the `PIVOT` clause names the resulting columns.

The other thing with `PIVOT` is that the possible values have to be explicitly named. You can get around that by using XML ([read more about how to do that](http://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php)), but then all your results will be XML-ized.

Comment: This worked pretty well, but I still would like to find a way to do it that doesn't require listing each analyte out individually.

Comment: I think `PIVOT` would be your only option, then, unless you're also comfortable with dynamic SQL.